# Working with Entity framework with Sitefinity and Portal Connector and Dynamic CRM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamics-crm, sitefinity

I'm working on a project that contains Dynamics CRM and Portal Connector which built upon Sitefinity.

There is a way to retrieve data inside Portal Connector from Dynamic CRM called [Saved Query](https://www.crmportalconnector.com/developer-network/documentation/how-tos/mvc-based-widgets/how-to-use-the-saved-queries-feature) and this way generate a URL for you to retrieve data by HTTP request in front-end but I don't want to access it by the front end I want to access the Dynamics CRM by Backened, specifically by Entity framework, is it possible to connect to Dynamic CRM by Entity framework and retrieve the data by C# then send it to View?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let me answer my question, in case anyone wants to do a similar thing in the future :

1- first thing connect to Dynamic CRM is not related to Portal Connector, so the area that you should search in is Dynamic CRM.

2- To connect to Dynamic CRM you should follow the below steps :
2.1- install this package  "Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly"
2.2- find what is your connection string.
2.3 use below code

```
var service=new CrmServiceClient("AuthType=Office365;Url=https://ititisdf.crm4.dynamics.com;Password=1234" )/*put your connection string instead*/
```

3- Some example of you could create or retrieved data

```
service.Create(new Entity("account"){["name]="Test connection"}); // add record

// retrive data

//1- query expression
//var query= new QueryExpression().Criteria. <===== from here you can add filteration ... and so on

//2- fetch xml expression
//var query=new FetchExpression(@"fetch xml value"); // you need to use XrmToolBox to generate your fetchXml

//3- var query=new  QueryByAttribute("account");
// query.AddAttributeValue("name","Test1");


var entities=service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;



foreach(var entity in entities)
{
entity["name"];
}

var organization=new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

// below code is under a concept called late-bound

var result=(from account in organization.CreateQuery("account")
join contact in organization.CreateQuery("contact") 
on account["primarcontactid"] equals contact["contactid"]
where account["gendercode"] == "test" AND account["industrycode"]=1
select new {

Name=account["name"],
ContactName=contact["fullname"]
}).ToList();
```

// to implement Early bound

1- go to XrmToolBox  ==> About ==> Plugin Store ==> Early Bound Generator==>Early Bound Generator Page  will opened choose Entity to skip and choose which entity to want to include and which want to exclude
===> choose the path of generated .cs class that will represent you Entity in your project  ===> press on Create Entities ===> now copy the generated file .

Now you have something like Entity framework :

Just use Entity name as a normal class :

```
var account = new Account{Name="Ahmed"};
```

and instead of this :

```
organization.CreateQuery("account")
```

use

```
organization.CreateQuery<yourEntityName>()
```

Actually, I got all of this information from youtube serious related to Dynamic, and here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-SE-u_jvb0&list=PLz0i9xjy6iLQ3UHPk7AcM-ZAxtpGUaxZo&index=27)

note: this serious in the Arabic language for this reason I summarised the steps in this answer to make it helpful for all.

Comment: Down voting as this bypasses the configured CRM connection in the Portal site and is prone to breaking when credentials change. Using the configured connection is the correct way to connect to CRM when using The Portal Connector.

Also, the CRM SDK is already installed in a Portal Connector site making that part incorrect as well.

Comment: I did put the correct answer but it was ignored for an incorrect "solution". My downvote stands.

Comment: @AdamBenoit put a correct answer to be accepted, it's not a personal issue dude :)

Comment: Certainly nothing personal. Your answer is still incorrect in the context of the question. I am Technical Lead for TPC and I train developers on the usage of our product. Simply saying my answer is incorrect without being able to back it up does our customers a disservice as it muddies the waters with incorrect information.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for not coming across your post sooner.

A better way is to use the CRM connection provided by the Portal Connector.  It essentially wraps the CRM SDK so calls you want make to the SDK can be made here and it uses the CRM connection configured in the site.

https://www.crmportalconnector.com/developer-network/documentation/developing-for-tpc/Dynamics-CRM-Connection-API

```
// Required usings
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using pavliks.PortalConnector.Crm.Connection; 

// The Code
// Create an instance of the connection manager
CrmConnectionManager manager = new CrmConnectionManager();

// Use the Connection property of the manager to access the 
// configured CRM connection and create a new account
Guid newId = manager.Connection.Create(new Entity("account")
{
    Attributes = new AttributeCollection()
    {
        {"name", "My Account Name"}
    }
});

// Create Query Expression
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account")
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
           
};

// Use manager to query CRM
EntityCollection entities = manager.Connection.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

All the required assemblies are already in the Sitefinity site bin folder as they come with the Portal Connector assemblies and are copied to that location with the Portal Connector during installation. If your code is in another project, either reference the assemblies in the Sitefinity project or add them from the Portal Connector deploy package to your project.

I know it's a bit late but I hope it helps you in your next portal project.